# How to use external JS library in Leaflet Angular2 Project

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I want to use leaflet-search plugin in my Leaflet Angular 2 Project to be able to search objects on the map. 
Here is js plugin https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search

My problem is that Leaflet doesn't see `Search`, for example if I try 
`L.Control.Search` I get `Search doesn't exists on type Control`.

What I have tried:

In `typings.d.ts`

```
declare var Search: any;
```

In `index.html`

```
<script src="../node_modules/leaflet-search/dist/leaflet-search.src.js">
</script>
```

And also in my `Component`

```
import '../../../../node_modules/leaflet-search/dist/leaflet-search.src.js';
```

And it still doesn't work...
How could I fix it?